# JSZip unzipping error

Tags: javascript, jszip

Trying to handle with [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip) library.

I am having an issue to unzip a file. Here's a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OJeWRhbDBKaPYAHb5x9b?p=preview). As you can see I can successfully zip a content, but when I try to unzip a zipped content I get an error (can be seen in console):

```
Uncaught Error: Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory
```

Any ideas why this happens?

In any case, here's what I am trying to achieve: I have an textarea on my page. Upon click I want to zip textarea content and send zipped data to server. Another call must be able to receive a zipped data, unzip it and replace textarea text with unzipped one. Everything works ok, except unzipping problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `generateAsync()` method defaults to a base64 output but the `loadAsync()` method only see a string.
You have two solutions :

- change the generated format with `generateAsync({type:"uint8array"}) (see [here](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html))
- or tell the load method that you are loading base64 content : `loadAsync(data,{base64:true})` (see [here](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html))

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. 8 years in and your comment has saved me hours of finding the resolution to this issue of loading base64 file. :)

Answer (score 0):

As answered by David has resolved my problem on my local workstation running Windows 10 OS. However it is failed on the Server running RHEL OS.

I have to fix it by switching to [yauzl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yauzl) package for unzipping. It is recommended as mention on package's official repository, with specified [merge pull 383](https://github.com/anmonteiro/lumo/pull/383).